# Google Cloud Deployment - User disabled

Tags: google-app-engine

Following [this instruction](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-deploy-a-static-react-site-to-google-cloud-platform-55ff0bd0f509), I try to deploy a front end app to Google Cloud. On the last step, I get the following error for the command "gcloud app deploy"

```
 (gcloud.app.deploy) Unable to deploy to application [my-app] with status [USER_DISABLED]: Deploying to stopped apps is not allowed.
```

I take a look at my Google Cloud account and can't find the disabled status.

Where shall I look to solve this problem?

Answer (score 19):

You should be able to re-enable your application by going to **App Engine** -> **Settings** when managing your project in the Google Cloud Platform Console.

Comment: The error is about the user. I can't see anything on the user in the setttings section.

Comment: @vic is the error in your question edited to replace your project-id with `my-app`? If not you need to specify which project you want to deploy to with the `--project <your-project-id-here>` option. Or set your default project with `gcloud config set project <your-project-id-here`.

Comment: Crucially, there seems to be a UX bug in the console UI which (if you haven't yet deployed) causes the sidebar (with the Settings menu entry in) to momentarily appear then disappear. The solution is to go into the main menu > App Engine > *hover* > then choose Settings directly from the pop-out menu. Then the sidebar appears and stays!!

Answer (score 6):

yeah you need to enable your application here

[image]

Comment: In my experience it is always better with a latest picture than words when it comes to explaining about a dashboard to the user

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible using the GCP CLI?
There's a command for starting a app version but I haven't found one for the app service.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is enabled in the App Engine Settings, you might not have selected the correct project:

```sh
gcloud config set project <app-engine-project-id>
```

You can see the ID in the right column after clicking on the project name in the Google Cloud Platform header on the website.