# How to deploy my php code in google cloud?

Tags: php, gcloud

I wrote a PHP code to retrieve data from big query and now i want to deploy it to google cloud. I installed gcloud sdk and `gcloud app deploy` code in cmd. But it shows the following error. 
[image]

Comment: I would highly recommend to take a look at the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831215/google-cloud-deployment-user-disabled) where a similar issue is posted, as well as two convincing answers. You should be able to re-enable your application by going to App Engine --> Settings when managing your project in GCP. I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The last error message says that it's not possible to deploy to a stopped app. I never used Google App Engine before but I would suggest that you take a look at your app's state on google app engine first. It may be in a sleeping state or something similar.

Sometimes, low traffic web app on Platform As A Service are put in hibernation mode (I'm not sure if that's the right word) after a certain time without usage.

I don't think the error has something to do with your app.yml or any other of your files anymore. Check your app's state on GAE first and try to deploy again.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. That was my fault. This error happen when the app engine doesn't work. So first of all we must go to the app engine and run it. Then we can deploy the code to cloud platform.